# winldap can't connect to openldap with ssl

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, openssl, ldap

- os : win7 64bits
- ldap server : [openldap for windows 2.4.34](http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx)
- compiler : vc2008

I can query the data of the server by this command

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://CS-GAMEBOY-PC -x -b dc=micmiu,dc=com -D cn=Manager,dc=micmiu,dc=com -w secret
```

But I can't query the data by the example codes of winldap(I remove most of the error handles and resource cleaning to simplify the codes)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winldap.h>
#include <winber.h>

int main()
{                                
    char *LdapServer = "CS-GAMEBOY-PC";
    LDAP *ldap = ldap_sslinitA(LdapServer, LDAP_SSL_PORT, 1);    

    unsigned long version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ldap_set_option(ldap,
                    LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                    (void*)&version);              

    //  If SSL is not enabled, enable it.
    ldap_set_option(ldap, LDAP_OPT_SSL, LDAP_OPT_ON);        

    // Connect to the server.
    unsigned long connectSuccess = ldap_connect(ldap, NULL);
    if(connectSuccess == LDAP_SUCCESS){
        std::cout<<"ldap_connect succeeded \n";
    }else{
        std::cout<<"ldap_connect failed with "<<ldap_err2string(connectSuccess)<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"error codes = 0x"<<std::hex<<connectSuccess<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }            
}
```

The ldap_connect fail and give me the error codes "0X51"

The server site give me the errors as

........
tls_read: want=5 error=Unknown error
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
........
tls_read: want=5 error=Unknown error
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
TLS: can't accept: (unknown).

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //
    static bool VerifyCert(void/*LDAP* ld, PCCERT_CONTEXT pServerCert*/)
    {
       return true;
    }
 //

..
//  Set the version to 3.0 (default is 2.0). and than ->

    ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, &VerifyCert);

// Now you can Bind.
..
```